# Go Pointers pointing to different memory locations but updating same variable

Tags: pointers, go, memory-address

**Summary:** `a` is pointing to a memory address of `0x40e020` which is assigned to `b`. `c`, is then assigned to `b`'s memory location (or so I thought). When I print out the address of c `&c` it points to a different spot in memory `0x40c138`.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var a int = 42
    b := &a
    c := b
    *c = 4

    fmt.Println(a, b, &c) // output --> 4 0x40e020 0x40c138

}
```

**Question**: How is the pointer `c` updating `a`'s value? I would expect `a` to print out 42, but the compiler spits out 4.

Comment: Your test output is invalid. `b` prints the address of `b`, but `&c` prints the address of a pointer to `c`.  In other words, `b` and `c` _are_ equal, but `b` and `&c` obviously aren't. See in the playground: https://play.golang.org/p/NV76oa6UjsN

Comment: You're not printing `c`'s value, you're printing the memory address of the variable `c` when you use `&c` in your `Println` statement.

Comment: @Adrian I'm aware I'm not printing ```c```'s value. I would like to know why or how ```c``` is updating ```a```'s value.

Comment: Because `c` is a pointer to `a`.

Comment: @Flimzy ```c``` is a pointer to ```a``` but ```c```'s  address is different. In essence, even though a variable has a different address it can still update any given variable through a pointer. Am I getting this correct?

Comment: Of course c's address is different. But that doesn't matter, because you're dereferencing it with `*c`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A picture might help.  Here is (some of) the memory in your computer, around 0x40c138 through 0x40e020 or so:

```
           +---------+                            +---------+
 ????????: |    *    | (variable "b")   0x40c138: |    *    | (variable "c")
           +----|----+                            +----|----+
                v      ________________________________/
           +---------+'
 0x40e020: |    4    | (variable "a")
           +---------+
```

Variables `b` and `c` both point to variable `a`.  You print the *value* of variable `b`, which is 0x40e020, which is how we know where `a` itself lives in memory.  You print the *address* of variable `c`, which is how we know where `c` itself lives in memory.  You do not print the address of variable `b` so we are not sure where it lives, but we do know that `b` and `c` both point to `a`, so we can draw the arrow coming out of each one.

Since the arrow coming out of `c` points to `a`, writing through `*c` writes to `a`.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down exactly what's happening here:

```
var a int = 42
b := &a
c := b
```

You now have three variables, each with its own location in memory. `a` is an integer with the value `42`. `b` and `c` each have the same value, which is the memory address of `a`.

```
*c = 4
```

This dereferences the pointer `c` and writes the value `4` to the memory location it points to, which is the memory location of `a`. This is why when printing `a` you see the value `4` - this line overwrites the value in `a`'s memory location. That's the primary purpose of pointers - to allow multiple references to the same value in memory.

```
fmt.Println(a, b, &c) // output --> 4 0x40e020 0x40c138
```

This prints the value of `a`, the value of `b` (which is the address of `a`), and the address of `c`.

Answer (score 0):

c prints the memory address of a. b is a variable that holds a's memory address and c is b (these variables hold the same value). 
When you print &c, you print the memory address of the variable c which holds a's memory address. 
The reason you can update a's value with c is because the * operator lets you access or follow the memory address c holds and update the value it is holding.